# BCM43225 not working on Lubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

the broadcom wireless card  bcm43225 is not working. I have tried with proprietary drivers and firmware-b43-installer package, with or without acer-wmi blacklisted. 
The card is not soft/hard blocked.

output of 'rfkill list'
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Can you suggest something?

Lubuntu 12.04 beta 2
Kernel 3.2.0-23-generic X86_64
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom bcm43225 rev 01 [14e4:4357]
Acer Travelmate 5735

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

My configuration: notebook acer 5742 - ubuntu 12.04 x32 - card wireless bcm43225

Solution for problem in my computer:

1. In the file: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"  disabled the line: "blacklist bcm43xx" posing as commentary.
2. At the command line:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source

Restart ubuntu ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the 3.3.3 kernel? I couldn't getting working wireless on the 3.1.x or 3.2.x kernels on the BCM43225 but 3.3.x seems to be working.

[Ubuntu 3.3.3-precise kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.3-precise/)

Comment: I have tried this morning with kernel 3.4rc4 and I have the same issue. According to Canonical developer, I have filed a bug report [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/987364)